# Check if a user has a role

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to check to see if a user has a certain role. I'm aware of @commands.has_role(), but that won't work for the context of what I'm making. I have example code below, and I'm not sure how I can get it to check if the user has the role.

```py
    @commands.command()
    async def hasthisroletest(self, ctx):
        if ctx.author.role.id == 746831268683186268:
            await ctx.send("You did it!")
        else:
            await ctx.send("Nope :(")
```

Comment: and what's the context of what you're making?

Answer (score 1):

You can check [Member.roles](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=roles#discord.Member.roles) if the wanted role is there.

Use [discord.utils.get](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get#discord.utils.get) to get the role itself.

```py
@commands.command()
async def hasthisroletest(ctx):
    # you can also use name = 'Test_role'
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id=746831268683186268)
    if role in ctx.author.roles:
        await ctx.send("You did it!")
    else:
        await ctx.send("Nope :(")
```